# Exclude elements in an array which do not contains specific decimals

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have an array that contains numbers with one decimal. The decimal can only be 1, 2 or 3 (set by user, therefor no need to be an algorithm). I want to create a function that excludes the elements in the array that do not contain all three decimals.

For example when considering the following array and expected out:

```
a = np.array([1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2])
b = np.array([1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 7.3, 7.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3])

#desired output
a_usefull = [1.1, 1.3, 1.2]
b_usebull = [1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3]
```

Element `2.1` and `2.2` in **a** is excluded since the decimal .3 is missing in both. Element `7.3` and `7.1` is excluded since decimal .2 is missing. NOTE that the order of the original array is import so for example `[1.3, 1.1, 1.2]` should come out as `[1.3, 1.1, 1.2]`

Another condition is that the output for for example  `[1.1, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 1.2, 2.3]` should be exactly as it can be seen. So for example it is [1,1,2,1,2,2] it should not be [1,1,1,2,2,2]. Order should not change.

I was thinking to floor all elements in the array and count them at first. However, the code should be given in a function. Can someone help with a while- or for loop for this one?

```
def remove(id):

return useful_elements
```

Thank you!

Comment: Bit ugly but `[k for k in a if all((int(k) + 0.1*i) in a for i in range(1, 4))]`

Comment: Are they always in order as in x.1, x.2, x.3?

Comment: Yes the output array should be in same order as original array. The decimals don't need to be in same order though. [2.3, 2.1, 2.2] is okay.

Comment: In that case, you can create your decimal list and check if that decimal list is a sublist of your input list @vectorizinglife that will have your decimals in order as well, as well your integer parts in the order check my answer below

Comment: @vectorizinglife I mean in the original list, are the numbers always in that order?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Okay thanks, will check that up.

Comment: @OmariCelestine No the original can be set in a random order 1.3 and come before 1.1 and so forth.

Comment: No problem @vectorizinglife let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by finding all the integer parts of the numbers from the list, make a list out of them, and then check if the list containing all three decimals exists in the bigger list

```
def func(li):

    res = []
    int_li = []

    #Create a list for integers in the input list
    for item in li:
        int_item = int(item)
        if int_item not in int_li:
            int_li.append(int_item)

    #Iterate through the list for integers
    for num in int_li:

        #Create list with all 3 decimals
        check_list = [(num + .1*i) for i in range(1, 4)]
        dec_list = []

        #Iterate through the bigger list
        for number in li:

            #Compare the integer part of element with given integer
            if num == int(number):
                dec_list.append(number)

            #If the found decimal list is present in bigger list with 3 decimals
            if sorted(dec_list) == sorted(check_list):
                #Add it to result and move on to next item
                res.extend(dec_list)
                break

    #Return result
    return res

print(func([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2]))
print(func([1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 7.3, 7.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3]))
```

The output will be

```
[1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
[1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and short

```
a = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2])

def remove(id):
    useful_elements=np.array([])
    for x in np.unique(a.astype(int)):
         if((x+.1 in a) and (x+.2 in a) and (x+.3 in a)):
             useful_elements=np.append(useful_elements,(x+.1,x+.2,x+.3))

    return useful_elements
```

Comment: Your code works but it changes the element's index number. If given [1.3, 1.1, 1.2] it changes it to [1.1, 1.2, 1.3] - I don't want that, but thank you for your simple and short code!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```
# your code goes here
import numpy as np
import math

a = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2])
b = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 7.3, 7.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3])

def numpy_filter(arr):
    required_decimals = {1, 2, 3}
    lst = arr.tolist()
    numbers = { math.floor(x) for x in lst }
    fmap = { n: { x for x in lst if math.floor(x) == n } for n in numbers }
    toReturn = []
    for n, decs in fmap.items():
        target_set = { n + x * 0.1 for x in required_decimals }
        if decs == target_set:
            toReturn.extend(target_set)
    return np.array(toReturn)

#desired output
print(numpy_filter(a))
print(numpy_filter(b))
a_usefull = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
b_usebull = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3]
```

First I extract the underlying list to more easily manage it

```
lst = arr.tolist()
```

Then I extract all the integer parts in a set to avoid duplicates

```
numbers = { math.floor(x) for x in lst }
```

After that I divide the original list in a map, mapping for each integer the contained elements that are in the original list

```
fmap = { n: { x for x in lst if math.floor(x) == n } for n in numbers }
```

After that, I parse all the elements of the map, looking for a difference between the one I have in the list and the one I should have. Anyone which maps is added to the new list which is returned.

```
toReturn = []
for n, decs in fmap.items():
    target_set = { n + x * 0.1 for x in required_decimals }
    if decs == target_set:
        toReturn.extend(target_set)
```

Here it is as [executable version](https://ideone.com/x2XU3T)